# Need help rewriting a math model.

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic, mathematical-modeling

Given signal $\beta\in\{0,1\}^p$, design matrix $X\in\{0,1\}^{n\times p}$, and observations $y\in\{0,1\}^n$, where the model is
\begin{align*}
y=X\beta(\mod 2)\text{, or equivalently }y_i=X_i^\top\beta(\mod 2).
\end{align*}
(Note that we are doing modulo arithmetic at each entry of $X\beta$.)

Can I rewrite the above model in another mathematical expression that doesn't use any modulo arithmetic or any floor/ceiling functions? Ideally I would like the output to be $y\in\{-1,+1\}^n$. So the idea is you can use other alphabets instead of 0 or 1 in $\beta$ and $X$, and instead of a (mod 2) function at each entry of $X\beta$, you are allowed to use other functions.

Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: "Other functions" is too broad. Are you fine with $y_i = (-1)^{(X \beta)_i}$?

Comment: Yes. I see what you are hinting at, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the previous comment from [ronno](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/32766/ronno) (thanks!), I managed to get the answer
\begin{align*}
y_i=\frac{1-(-1)^{X_i^\top\beta}}{2}.
\end{align*}